# Question about a change of variable used to compute $E(X)$ from the CDF of $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

I was studying a proof where the author shows that if the range of x is $\mathbb R_+$ and $F$ is the cumulative distribution function then:

$$E[X] = \int_{0}^\infty (1-F(x))dx $$

However on one part of the proof, when integrating by parts, he states that if

$$ dv = -f(x)$$ then $$ v = 1-F(x)$$

I do know that $$ F(a)= \int_{-\infty}^a f(x) dx$$

but I can´t find a way to understand why the $-1$ of in the expression of $v$.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You understand why $v=F$ yields $dv=f(x)dx$ but not why $v=1-F$ yields $dv=-f(x)dx$?

Comment: I corrected the tags and some inconsiderate uses of $X$ for $x$ in the question.

Comment: Yes, indeed I would like to get an interpretation of $-f(x)$

Comment: It seems I have to repeat: if $v=F$, you know $dv$ but if $v=1-F$ you cannot compute $dv$?

Comment: No, it´s the other way around if $dv=-f(x)$ how can I compute $v$? Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, $1-F$ is a *primitive* of $-f$, isn't it? (Note that $dv=-f(x)$ is absurd, you probably mean $dv=-f(x)dx$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, but you need to be able to justify an interchange of an iterated integral.

You have $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x) dx$ and $EX = \int_0^\infty x f(x) dx$.

Write $x = \int_0^x dt$ to get $EX = \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{t=0}^x f(x) dtdx$. All the quantities are positive, so we can switch the order of integration to get
$EX = \int_{t=0}^\infty \int_{x=t}^\infty f(x)dx dt$. Since we have
$F(t)+ \int_{x=t}^\infty f(x)dx dt = 1$, we get
$EX = \int_{t=0}^\infty (1-F(t))dt$, which is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That´s a very different approach, I was wondering if there is any interpretation that I can give to $-f(x)$ since on the other approach of the demonstration they integrate it directly to get $1-F(x)$ ? Do you have any idea how they get to that result?

Comment: I don't. If you let $\phi(x) = x (1-F(x))$ and differentiate you get $\phi'(x) = (1-F(x))-x f(x)$. However to use integration by parts I need to show that $\phi(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ which is not necessarily true.